# Slicing Pandas DataFrame with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have chrologically sorted DataFrame, lets take this one for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('2011-04-01 00:00', periods=300, freq='min')

random_dates = pd.to_datetime(np.random.choice(dates, size=20,replace=False)).sort_values()

numbers = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(20,))

df = pd.DataFrame(index=random_dates, data=numbers)
```

If we print it:

```
...
2011-04-01 02:03:00 -0.404476
2011-04-01 02:38:00  0.205260
2011-04-01 02:44:00  0.111812
2011-04-01 03:10:00 -0.071028
2011-04-01 03:55:00 -0.203999
```

How to get rows that fall into last N minutes/hours of the DataFrame timeindex?

So for example if I'd like to have last hour (counting from the last row) I'd get last two rows from the example above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is sorted by index, you can subtract an arbitrary amount of time from the final index entry using `pd.Timedelta`.

Then just filter your dataframe based on `df.index`.

```
lower_range = df.index[-1] - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)

df = df.loc[df.index > lower_range]

print(df)

#                             0
# 2011-04-01 04:10:00 -0.116102
# 2011-04-01 04:59:00  0.364772
```